# Log messages are not available in Google App Script Executions

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-cloud-stackdriver

In the executions section of the App Scripts Dashboard I can see entries for each execution. However, most recently I'm not able to expand execution entries to see the detailed log messages.

An execution I ran directly from the HEAD deployment editor does expand to show log messages, but executions of published versions running as a webapp do not have log messages.

[image]

I remember this working before? Did something change with how App Scripts handles logging?

Comment: Known issue. Consider creating a issue in issuetracker after searching for similar issues. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Ah yes I've found two similar issues, but unfortunately no solution from Google yet.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161298393, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134374008

Comment: Consider starring the issue(top left) to prioritize the issue and commenting on it.